# Customizing cross validation in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I have a group of features for each player's replay, and a target value at different time-slices. I'm doing classification by Scikit-learn. To do cross-validation, I should put a constraint such that if a sample of a replay are in train set, then there should be no other sample from that replay in the test set.  Should I define a function to split the data or I could customize the craoss validation function in Scikit-learn?

**Edit 1**

Suppose my data matrix is as follow: replayID, time slice, and features for this row. Also I have an array that include class labels.

```
             replayID Time_slice Features
data=array([[ 100,     0.,     1.5,...],
           [ 100,      1.,       3.7,...],
           [ 100,      0.,       1.2,...],
           [ 100,      1.,       1.8,...],
           [ 100,      2.,       2.9,...],
           [ 101,      0.,       1.5,...],
           [ 101,      1.,       3.7,...],
           [ 101,      0.,       1.2,...],
           [ 101,      1.,       1.8,...],
           [ 101,      2.,       2.9,...]])
```

I require if a sample with replayID =100 is in training data, then there is no other samples with replayID=100 in test data. Moreover, the training data should be 80% of data and test data, 20%.

```
X = data[:, 1:]
y = targets
labels = data[:, 0]
cv = LabelKFold(labels, n_folds=10)
est = GradientBoostingClassifier(**params)
for train, test in cv:
     X_train = X[train]
     y_train = y[train]
     X_test = X[test]
     est.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Please state your problem more clearly, such that it is not up to interpretation of potential answerers what you are trying to do. Generally a code example would be awesome, but here it may not be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contemporary versions of `sklearn.cross_validation` already contain versions for what you're asking - those containing the word `Label`. E.g.,

- [`LabelKFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#label-k-fold)
- [LeavePLabelOut`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#leave-p-label-out)
- etc.

Comment: If I employ LabelKFold method, how can I split the train and test data to 80% and 20% respectively.